# Paypal Express checkout - which one should I use Classic API Vs Rest API

Tags: paypal-rest-sdk, paypal

Is paypal express checkout supported or not. While downloading the merchannt SDK samples I found this 
"This Classic SDK is not actively supported and will be deprecated in the future. For full support on new integrations, please use the PayPal REST API SDK for .NET"

I need the express check out option. Which one should I use?

I am kind of confused. Can I use merchant SDK the classic one or go with the REST API?

Comment: It's going to be a long while before they get rid of the Classic API (if ever).  I still prefer it myself and use it within all my apps.

Comment: it depends which is gonna suits u and you are getting easy to work with ..i personally using classic api and its working fine

Answer (score 0):

The message about deprecation for the SDK is a bit misleading.  PayPal have [new REST APIs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-payments-overview/) and also the [Braintree v.zero SDKs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/ios+ruby/), and these are the products that should be used for integrations going forward for the vast majority of merchants.

However, for enterprise merchants, and especially customers with specific product features that are not currently supported on the new platforms, Express Checkout is still the best solution, and it will continue to be for some time.  So the deprecation message is intended to guide to the new APIs, rather than indicate a lack of support or functionality.

[PaySharp.NET](https://github.com/daishisystems/Daishi.PaySharp) is an open source .NET SDK, and should meet your requirements, given that it is specifically designed to support Express Checkout. [Here is an in-depth tutorial](http://insidethecpu.com/2015/09/25/paypal-express-checkout-with-paysharp-net/) on the subject.